# Enabling Server Filtering, Sorting, Paging breaks SignalR Client Updates for MVC Kendo UI Grid

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I created an application using the Teleirk MVC wrapper for Kendo UI grid with a SignalR datasouce.

An update of the grid was transmitted and reflected on all clients running the application perfectly (with client side filtering, sorting, paging). The datasource I was using was rather large (which caused some performance issues with the filtering, sorting, paging operations). So I then re-configured my grid to use server filtering, sorting, paging which did fixed my performance issue and drastically improved the usability of the application.

After I reconfigured to move those actions server-side I noticed a change I was making was not being reflected on all the client machines. I then switched back and forth between client-side and server-side filtering, sorting, and paging to verify that that change was the cause of my issue to be sure.

Has anyone experiences this before themselves? And can you provide me with steps/advice on how to fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Telerik provided me with the solution. Here is the thread with the answer:

[http://www.telerik.com/forums/enabling-server-filtering-sorting-paging-breaks-signalr-client-updates-for-mvc-kendo-ui-grid#HsK5Fb_TqE-jnM98lZZrUQ][1]

If you are using `DataSourceRequest` and `DataSourceResult` inside your SignalR Hub class you need to ensure that all methods return the same type:

```
        public DataSourceResult Read(DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var result = _dataService.Read().AsQueryable().ToDataSourceResult(request);
            return result;
        }

        public void Update(ProductTitlePartsBySku item)
        {
            _dataService.Update(item);
            Clients.Others.update(item);
        }
```

In this scenario the `Clients.Others.update` call returns the item - it should be:

```
Clients.Others.update(new DataSourceResult
{
    Data = new[] { item }
});
```

You must also ensure that you set the .Data options etc in the Grid view:

```
    .Schema(schema => schema
        .Data("Data")
        .Total("Total")
        .Aggregates("Aggregates")
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(m => m.IDCOLUMN);
            model.Field(m => m.IDCOLUMN).Editable(false);
        })
    )
```

This ensures the grid knows it has to bind to the Data property of the DataSourceResult

Comment: But I don't see with the solution how the update respects the client specific filter, sorting and paging settings. The update would be sent even though the item might appear on page 2 while the client is currently on page 1. Any idea how to tackle this?